# How do I display articles in sticky footer?

Tags: views, blocks

Not sure if i am going about this the right way but my intended goal is this:

Create a sticky footer that displays:

1. In Section 1(Left section) a Link to Latest magazine issue.
2. In Section 2 (Right Section) 
   A. Either show the latest Archived Articles.
   B. Allow a user to input or select their own desired archived article.

Can I use a view to display this, or should I use a block? If I can accomplish this with a view, what should my approach be?

> [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you number of archive and data in this block all always this (not need generate dynamic)  you can  create them  with 2 static block that their link  redirect user to a page that data was generated by views,(views page ).

and if you block data is not static and you want they generate dynamically I suggest you use `views block(this mean a view with block display)`.

I think [this link](http://www.webbykat.com/2012/02/creating-monthly-archive-block-drupal-7-views) can help you it describe how to create a block that show month name and when click on each month  related data  according to the that month fetch by view.

Comment: Looks like a workable solution.... After reviewing the link i forgot to mention that i am using the panels module. Will this work if i add the the view block to the region with the panels module enabled?

Comment: @cthrucode yes, you can , there is no  problem